# How do I replace column values of a dataframe with values of another dataframe based on a common column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one that looks like this:

hec_df:

| accident year | factor | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2007 | 1.5 | 13 |
| 2008 | 1.6 | 11 |
| 2009 | 1.7 | 15 |

and hec_ldfs:

| accident year | factor |
| --- | --- |
| 2007 | 1.6 |
| 2008 | 1.64 |
| 2009 | 1.7 |

My goal is to replace the factor value of df1 with the factor value of df2. My code for this is

```
hec_df['factor'] = hec_df['factor'].map(hec_ldfs.set_index('accident year')['factor'])
```

But it returns NaN on the factor column. Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: I'm not sure why my first dataframe is formatted like that, does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

you're mapping factor to the accident_year, instead of hec_df.accident_year to the hec_df.accident year

```
hec_df['factor'] = hec_df['accident year'].map(hec_ldfs.set_index('accident year')['factor']).fillna(hec_df['factor'])
hec_df
```

```
accident year   factor  age
0   2007    1.60    13
1   2008    1.64    11
2   2009    1.70    15
```

Comment: I tested this, and fillna is not required for the sample data provided. --- However, If there was missing data in `hec_ldfs` (the second df), `fillna` would fill the newly built `hec_df['factor']` Series using the original values in `hec_df['factor']`.

Comment: @ferreiradev, fillna, is a fail-safe to avoid a NaN. If OP is certain of not having a null scenario, it can be safely removed.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! An additional follow up question: can you use the map function to use two or more indexes? For example, if I needed the lookup to use accident year as well as segment, could I do that?

Comment: Map works with dictionary. One way to make use of two fields is to create a temp field combining two column and use that to map. Hope it helps.